# Can't install json (Ruby doesn't work)

Tags: json, rubygems

windows 10. ruby 2.2.4. I've tried all the devkit stuff and whatever to fix this. I've looked stuff up for hours and hours with no success. When I try to bundle it doesn't install json. When I try to install json it says

```
"Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160303-4132-alefq2.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

make "DESTDIR="
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. The `Gemfile.lock` in the repo I cloned had a json version older than the one I had already installed. I did not manage to uninstall the newer version, but I did replace the old version number in the `Gemfile.lock` with the new one and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the [devkit installation scripts](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit#4-run-installation-scripts).
In particular, pay attention to [devkitvars.bat](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit#accessing-the-full-msysmingw-environment).

Comment: I've already done that, the steps go through fine but when I do "gem install json --platform=ruby" it gives me errors saying "failed to build gem native extension" "make "DESTDIR=" clean" "make is not recognized as an internal or external command" "Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection." and some other stuff. I've tried everything on the internet to fix this.